# how to have windsor container disposing instance w/ Lifestyle=Thread

Tags: castle-windsor

I'm using windsor container into a win service.
I'm using Linq2sql for persistence purpose.
An instance of Linq2Sql DC has been injected into 2 component UnitOfWork and Repository
I might set Lifestyle to Singleton for DC+UoW+Repository, but I'm concern in a long-term my Dc will hold to many enitites affecting memory without any reason for my app: after I'm done with an entity I won't use it anymore, but there's no public method on DC to clear cache.

Due my DC will injected into 2 components, I cannot use Lifestyle.Transient otherwise 2 instances will be created(one per each injection)

So I decided to set Lifestyle to Thread: my app has timer to execute a job every n minutes, on each ticking I kick a new thread.
In that case a new DC will be create on each thread and that injected into 2 cmps as above. Since disposing policy for Lifestyle=Thread are same as singleton(on container disposing/end of my app/on stop), I'm concern about amount of object hold into container until winservice will be stopped.

Since I call Join() on my thread, I exaclty now when it will be over. I was thinking to 
extract from the container my 3 objs and call dispose, but I don't like this approach: I prefer have the container dealing with his own objects...

Any comments/suggestion?

I was also thinking to create my own Lifestyle to accomplish my disposing at the end of the thread, basically simulating what happend into a web scenario with PerWebRequest(at the end of the request all cmps will be disposed). Is there any sample how to create custom Lifestyle?

Comment: which version are you using? Per-Thread disposes instances when the container is disposed.

Comment: I'm using 2.5. Yes, Thanks I noticed/read about Per-Thread will be disposed on container disposing. i wonder if there's away to have cmps created Per-Thread disposed at the moment Thread is over.
As workaround I decided to create and dispose my container into same thread: doing this I'm sure my cmp will be creatd once injected into other cmps into same thread and than diposed as I wish at the end of the thread

Comment: There's no way to detect diagrammatically that a thread is ending AFAIK

Comment: Cristiano, I met the same problem today, when dealing with Castle for our socket service. Have to do the same way as you do, but also call release for each element that I have resolved as transient & per thread (they say "release what you explicitly resolve") when our thread class dispose. Not sure about Singleton Lifestyle though, will they remain shared among the thread?

Comment: @Hoang did you try the "new" scoped lifestyle? https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/lifestyles.md

Comment: @CristianoDegiorgis: not yet. I have read about it, however it seems it's a little bit unclear... I would save it until later then.